# Over 30% drop in traffic

Tags: google, traffic, optimization

I have a site based on tutorials about stuff I learned and shared them to the world. Its true that we (me and my friend) started writing less on the blog due to us being busy with some other projects. Anyway, the site has been growing steady for the past few months now, a few days ago we noticed a drop in traffic of about 30% to 40%.

I've also had 2 IPs assigned to this website and one of these IPs unfortunately had some issues and no traffic could be sent to it for around a week or so and just the other day fixed it. In this time, if the site was receiving visits to that IP, it would be getting errors due to connection issues.

Nothing much was changed on the site, we just woken up and saw the drop in traffic.

Has anyone else experience this? Does anyone have any advice to fix this or just wait for google to pickup that the site is back to normal?

Most of the visits, over 85% come from google, surprisingly adsense performs the same or even better.

Looking forward for any advice on this.

Bogdan

Comment: There was another panda update at that time